# Android java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a dream dictionary, i'm reading from a txt file and saving to array for displaying it to a listview. But there are some errors from the log cat, can anybody tell me what is wrong.

```
    05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sonovnik.petkovski/com.sonovnik.petkovski.Main}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at com.sonovnik.petkovski.Main.readTxt(Main.java:115)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at com.sonovnik.petkovski.Main.initStuff(Main.java:131)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at com.sonovnik.petkovski.Main.onCreate(Main.java:39)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
05-07 14:29:06.750: E/AndroidRuntime(29135):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the code:

```
    public class Main extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<Son> sonovi;
    private EditText filterText = null;
    private SonovnikAdapter adapter;
    private ListView list;
    Translator t = new Translator();
    private Intent intent;
    private ArrayList<Son> temp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initStuff();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                intent.putExtra("opis", sonovi.get(position).getOpis());
                intent.putExtra("naslov", sonovi.get(position).getNaslov());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String test = filterText.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                int dolzina = filterText.length();
                temp = new ArrayList<Son>();
                for (int i = 0; i < sonovi.size(); i++) {
                    if (filterText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals(
                                    (String) sonovi.get(i).getLatinicno().toLowerCase()
                                            .subSequence(0, dolzina))) {
                        temp.add(sonovi.get(i));
                    }

                }

                SonovnikAdapter testc = new SonovnikAdapter(Main.this,
                        R.layout.item, temp);
                list.setAdapter(testc);
                testc.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        intent.putExtra("opis", temp.get(position).getOpis());
                        intent.putExtra("naslov", temp.get(position)
                                .getNaslov());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

    private ArrayList<Son> readTxt() {
        ArrayList<Son> s = new ArrayList<Son>();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sonovnik);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String str = null;
        String naslov, opis, latinica;
        String[] tmp;
        try {
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tmp = str.split("-");
                naslov = tmp[0].toString();
                opis = tmp[1].toString();

                latinica = tmp[2].toString(); //line 115
                 Log.v("test", latinica);
                s.add(new Son(naslov, opis, latinica));
            }
            is.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

    private void initStuff() {
        list = getListView();
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        sonovi = new ArrayList<Son>();
        sonovi = readTxt(); //line 131
        intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
        adapter = new SonovnikAdapter(this, R.layout.item, sonovi);
        setListAdapter(this.adapter);
        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    }

    private class SonovnikAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Son> {

        private ArrayList<Son> items;

        public SonovnikAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Son> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            Son o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                TextView naslov = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                if (naslov != null) {
                    naslov.setText(o.getNaslov().toString());
                }
            }
            return v;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
            tmp = str.split("-");
            naslov = tmp[0].toString();
            opis = tmp[1].toString();

            latinica = tmp[2].toString(); //line 115
```

You split the string using "-" as a delimiter, but you never check into how many pieces it was actually split. Apparently, your input text file contains some line that has only one "-" in it, so it is split into only two pieces, and tmp[2] is out of range.

Also, there is no need for calling .toString(), since tmp is already an array of strings.

Comment: Ah, assylias was faster than me. :-)

Comment: lol me too, but it's all good, we all gave similar answer , doesn't really matter, someone else will see it useful. Someday...

Answer (score 1):

In `readText`, you have:

```
tmp = str.split("-");
```

Then you use `tmp[0]`, `tmp[1]` and `tmp[2]`. My guess is that `tmp.length < 2`.

What makes you think that tmp will have at least 3 items? Even if you think it should be the case, you should test for it: `if (tmp.length >=3) {` etc.

Side note: tmp[i] is already a String so there is no need to write `xxx = tmp[i].toString();`, `xxx = tmp[i];` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that str = br.readLine() will always have a "-" ? What I can see here is that, If one of your str (str = br.readLine() )does not contain a  "-", you won't have a tmp[0] and or tmp[1] which may lead to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
You may want to do a check to see if you can split by a  "-" by checking if(str.contains("-"))

```
  String[] tmp;
try {
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
       //before split, check that delimeter exists                      
        if (str.contains("-")) {
            tmp = str.split("-");
            naslov = tmp[0].toString();
            opis = tmp[1].toString();
         .......            
         }                          
    }
    is.close();
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```